# Mac Terminal unzip zip64

Tags: terminal, zip, unzip

I have Mac OS 10.9.5. I have downloaded a large zip file off of the internet that the owner changed to a zip64 for me so it could work. I try unzipping the file with `unzip SNPsnap_gcan_3_500.zip` but I get the following error

`End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of SNPsnap_gcan_3_500.zip or
        SNPsnap_gcan_3_500.zip.zip, and cannot find SNPsnap_gcan_3_500.zip.ZIP, period.`

I have no clue how to unzip this file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 42):

without any installation, comes with the OS.

open a terminal window (e.g. cmd + space -> terminal -> Enter>

enter `ditto -xk YourZipfile.zip ./`

works.

Comment: wouldn't that just copy my zip file to everywherE?

Comment: `/` would be root. `./` means the current directory. note the dot!

Comment: Thanks! That's the correct tool, `ditto` works just fine and ships with the OS.

Answer (score 31):

`ditto` for whatever reason doesn't appear to have a 'list' option.

If you use 7zip (which can be installed via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/),) the `7za` binary has zip64 support.

In my case I was trying to extract the Modern.IE Windows 10 VM image...

```
$ 7za l 'Microsoft Edge.Win10.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'  # list zip contents

$ 7za e 'Microsoft Edge.Win10.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip' # extract
```

Comment: Note that 7za has two different options for extraction, 'e' and 'x'. Only x recreates the directory tree - I got stumped with the very same Windows VM images.

Comment: To install via briew: `brew install p7zip`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `unzip -l myfile.zip` will list CPIO or PKZip files just fine.

Comment: The OS-bundled unzip can't seem to decompress Zip64 archives. Tested with `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009` from Sonoma 14.1.2